# OpenMP: Run 2 thread groups in parallel

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to have 2 threads groups run at the same time. For example, 2 threads are executing code block 1 and another 2 threads are executing another code segment. There was a stackoverflow question here [OpenMP: Divide all the threads into different groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556748/openmp-divide-all-the-threads-into-different-groups) and I changed the code to see if it suits the logic I need in my code.

I have the below code with me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 1

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    omp_set_nested(1);   /* make sure nested parallism is on */
    int nprocs = omp_get_num_procs();
    int nthreads1 = NUM_THREADS;
    int nthreads2 = NUM_THREADS;

    int t1[nthreads1];

    for (int i=0; i<nthreads1; i++) {
        t1[i] = 0;
    }

#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(nthreads1, nthreads2, t1) num_threads(2)
    #pragma omp single
    {
        #pragma omp task                                            // section 1
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads1)  shared(t1)
        for (int i=0; i<nthreads1; i++) {
            printf("Task 1: thread %d of the %d children of %d: handling iter %d\n",
                        omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_team_size(2),
                        omp_get_ancestor_thread_num(1), i);
            t1[i] = 1;
        }
        #pragma omp task                                            // section 2
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads2)  shared(t1, t2)
        for (int j=0; j<nthreads2; j++) {
            while (!t1[j]) {
                printf("Task 2: thread %d of the %d children of %d: handling iter %d\n",
                            omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_team_size(2),
                            omp_get_ancestor_thread_num(1), j);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To check if my code is running 2 thread groups at once, I set the thread count in each group to 1 and then I keep a boolean list that is initialized to 0.
In the first code segment, I set the boolean value to 1, and in the 2nd code segment, I check the boolean value to break out of the while loop. It seems like the above code is only run by 1 thread, because if the thread starts running the 2nd code block/section, then it keeps stuck inside the while loop because another thread is not setting the boolean value to 1.

How to run 2 thread groups in parallel?

UPDATE: My use case: I am writing a word count map-reduce program using OpenMP. I want one thread group 2 read files which adds read lines to a queue. I want another thread group to process lines from those queues and update the counts in a chained hash table. I already wrote the code to first do the reading to formulate the queues and then do the mapping to take data from queues and generate word counts -- but I want to change my program to have 2 thread groups to do reading and mapping in parallel -- at the same time. That's why I made this shortcode to check how I can implement 2 thread groups, running in parallel executing 2 different code segments.

Comment: Irrespective of the rest of the code, what you are missing here is some `#pragma omp flush` directives. Just add one right after the `t1[i] = 1;` line and another right after the `printf()` in the second section...

Comment: Alternatively to the Gilles' comment, you can use atomic directives (or the costly critical sections). Variables are kept coherent between threads using caches on modern architectures. But cache or different cores are not always fully synchronized because this is costly. Thus, you *need* to tell to your processor that you perform some manual communication/synchronization between your threads so it can synchronize the value of the variable between cores.

Comment: Are you saying that the above code runs 2 threads in parallel doing different work? @Gilles? I added the `#pragma omp flush directive` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Since I am using shared(t1) when I declare the #pragma omp directive. Does synchronization really matter in this case? I mean, if one thread sets the boolean to 1, then the other thread should be able to break out of the while loop, right? It seems like only one thread is running at a time. @JérômeRichard

Comment: Yes synchronization matters. You should not assume threads have a *synchronized view* of the memory because on some platforms one thread can change a shared variable and the other threads do not see the modification. I am not able to reproduce the problem on my machine. So the problem is likely platform dependent (which is coherent with the previous message). Can you add information regarding your platform (processor, system, compiler, etc.) in your question as well as an example of output? Besides this, you can try to use OpenMP sections rather than tasks in that case.

Comment: I am executing the server in a Linux server with mpicc compiler. The output I am seeing is `Task 2: thread %d of the %d children of %d: handling iter %d` getting printed again and again on the terminal but sometimes if section 1 runs first, the code does not execute the print statement inside the section 2 code block. That's why I mentioned earlier that the same boolean is seen by both the sections even without synchronized updates. @JérômeRichard
I tried with sections also but it didn't seem to work either. But then I solved the problem using tasks and single nowait directives.

Comment: "I want to have 2 threads groups run at the same time." Why? What is your real problem? (As you can see, this doesn't seem a simple solution, but if we knew the real problem we might be able to suggest one...)

Comment: Here is my use case @JimCownie. I am writing a word count map-reduce program using openmp. I want one thread group 2 read files which adds read lines to a queue. I want another thread group to process lines from those queues and update the counts in a chained hash table. I already wrote the algo to first do the reading and then do the mapping but I want to change my program to have 2 thread groups to do reading and mapping in parallel. That's why I made this shortcode to check how I can implement 2 thread groups, running in parallel executing 2 different code segments.

Comment: I suggest you submit that as a question, then we can answer it. Giving the answer to how to do that here is not appropriate since my answer for that would not answer the mechanistic question you asked here. I would try to be much more abstract... (and probably use OPenMP tasks).

Comment: I updated the description @JimCownie with the use case. The entire code for map-reduce program is too large to post here, with multiple files. That's why I wrote the above basic code because that part is the only relevant part to support the map-reduce problem.

Comment: I have written a blog post at CPU-fun which discusses solutions to your real problem. It may be helpful (or not :-( ). https://cpufun.substack.com/p/processing-a-file-with-openmp

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the above could be solved using single directives with nowait and task directives. The below approach puts the tasks on to a queue and then threads pickup work from the queue. So ideally, 2 thread groups will be working on 2 different tasks, which is what is required in the question. Below is the code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 1

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    omp_set_nested(1);   /* make sure nested parallism is on */
    int nprocs = omp_get_num_procs();
    int nthreads1 = NUM_THREADS;
    int nthreads2 = NUM_THREADS;
    int t1[nthreads1];
    for (int i=0; i<nthreads1; i++) {
        t1[i] = 0;
    }
    #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(nthreads1, nthreads2, t1)
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait                                            // section 1
        for (int i=0; i<nthreads1; i++) {
            #pragma omp task
            {
                printf("Task 1: thread %d of the %d children of %d: handling iter %d\n",
                            omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_team_size(2),
                            omp_get_ancestor_thread_num(1), i);
                t1[i] = 1;
            }
        }
        #pragma omp single nowait                                            // section 2
        for (int j=0; j<nthreads2; j++) {
            #pragma omp task
            {
                while (!t1[j]) {
                    printf("Task 2: thread %d of the %d children of %d: handling iter %d\n",
                                omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_team_size(2),
                                omp_get_ancestor_thread_num(1), j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, you can simply use an if-else statement inside the `#pragma omp` construct to run 2 threadgroups in parallel

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 2

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    omp_set_nested(1);   /* make sure nested parallism is on */
    int nprocs = omp_get_num_procs();
    int nthreads1 = NUM_THREADS/2;
    int nthreads2 = NUM_THREADS/2;
    int t1[nthreads1];
    for (int i=0; i<nthreads1; i++) {
        t1[i] = 0;
    }
    #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(t1) num_threads(NUM_THREADS) {
        int i = omp_get_thread_num(); // section 1
        if (i<nthreads1) {
            printf("Section 1: thread %d\n",i);
            t1[i] = 1;
        } else {
            int j = i - nthreads1;
            while (!t1[j]) {
                printf("Section 2: thread %d, shift_value %d\n", i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I strongly doubt this solve the problem in a portable way... Using another OpenMP runtime and/or compiler should results in different results... Indeed, I think using 2 `omp single nowait` rather than one should not have any visible effect regarding the OpenMP standard, but it can result in a different behaviour of the runtime. Note that the implementation/behaviour of runtime is not guaranteed and thus may change in a (near) future.

Comment: It works with single nowait also but I don't really know how the compiler would handle these in lower levels. For my use case, both seem to work. @JérômeRichard