# choose different threads for diffrent tasks in a fortran code by using openmp

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

```
program main

USE OMP_LIB
IMPLICIT NONE

 INTEGER :: i,j,mm,m1,a,k,a1,b,bvv
 logical :: nn

call omp_set_nested(.true.)
call omp_set_max_active_levels(2)
CALL omp_set_num_threads(2)



!$omp parallel do private(j,mm,i,bvv) &
!$omp reduction (+:b)

   DO j=1, 2
   mm=omp_get_thread_num()

!$omp parallel do shared(mm,j) private(i,bvv) 

   DO i = 1, 2
    b=b+1
    bvv=omp_get_thread_num()
   WRITE(*,'(A,I2,2x,A,I2,I2,I2)')'DO1_THREAD',mm, 'DO2_Thread ',bvv  ,i,j
   END DO

!$omp end parallel do


  enddo
  

!$omp end parallel do 

print*,b
end program main
```

This is my code.

How can i manage threads assignment like below in openmp fortran code for CALL omp_set_num_threads(2):

```
             0------------------- 1
            |                     |
            |                     |
       ----------            ------------
     |            |          |           |
     |            |          |           |                                                        
     2            3          4           5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenMP: Divide all the threads into different groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556748/openmp-divide-all-the-threads-into-different-groups)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, using openmp tasks for the second level.

```
program main

USE OMP_LIB
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: i,j,mm,k1,k2,bvv,b
real :: x=0.0, y=0.0

CALL omp_set_num_threads(6)

!$omp parallel do private(mm,i,bvv,k2) &
!$omp             firstprivate(x,y) &
!$omp             shared(b)
DO j=1, 2
    mm=omp_get_thread_num()

    DO i = 1, 2
        !$omp task shared(b) &
        !$omp      private(bvv,k1) &
        !$omp      firstprivate(x)
        bvv=omp_get_thread_num()
        !$omp atomic update
        b=b+1
        WRITE(*,'(A,I2,2x,A,I2,I2,I2)')'DO1_THREAD',mm, 'DO2_Thread ',bvv,i,j
        
        do k1 = 1, 1000000
            x = cos(x)
        end do
        
        !$omp end task
    END DO

    do k2 = 1, 1000000
        y = cos(y)
    end do

enddo
!$omp end parallel do

print*,b
end program main
```

Note that:

- For demonstration, I have introduced fake loops in order to have enough workload in each thread, otherwise the tasks simply reuse some threads
- I can't see how to update b without an atomic operation, as reductions don't work with tasks. Another possibility would be to declare an array b(<number of threads>) and sum it at the end of the program.
- I'm not sure why you would want fully separate threads for the inner loop instead of reusing some threads of the outer loop, but why not... This has sense only if the outer loop has some workload outside of the inner loop.

Here is the output:

```
DO1_THREAD 0  DO2_Thread  3 1 1
DO1_THREAD 1  DO2_Thread  5 1 2
DO1_THREAD 0  DO2_Thread  4 2 1
DO1_THREAD 1  DO2_Thread  2 2 2
           4
```