# nested parallelism by using only MPI

Tags: nested, fortran, mpi

```
  program main


  implicit none
  include "mpif.h"


  integer nproc,rank,ierr,a(4),ll,i,j
 
  call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,nproc,ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,rank,ierr)
  
  ll=0
  a(:)=0

      do i=1,4
        do j=1,4
           a(i)=a(i)+1
           a(j)=a(j)+1
             ll=ll+1
        enddo
     enddo

  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr) 

  end program main
```

This is my code. I want to make these two loops parallel ,i.e. "nested parallel". In the end, a(:) must be a(:)=8, and ll must be ll=16. How can i do this by using only two threads (0 and 1) by using only MPI?

```
  (1,2) 0---------------------1 (3,4)   -----------> i loop
        |                     |
        |                     |
 0-------------1         0--------------1
 |             |         |              |
 |             |         |              |                                                        
(1,2)        (3,4)      (1,2)          (3,4)  ---------> j loop
```

Comment: You have asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77059825/choose-different-threads-for-diffrent-tasks-in-a-fortran-code-by-using-openmp) one week ago, and never gave any feedback on the comment and answer that had been posted. Needless to say that it does give a lot of motivation to answer this one.

Comment: And the mpi include file shouldn't be used nowadays. Use one of the modules.

Comment: As Ian said, avoid `include "mpif.h"`. Use `use mpi`, which uses the same API, but is better, or learn `use mpi_f08`, that is the modern way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: MPI does not use threads, it's based on processes. Since processes have separate data spaces, that means you can not have the MPI processes act on some shared object.

And that brings me to the main point: you need to split your data object over the processes. Here you have two options:

1. You can create your array on process 0, distribute it, operate on it in parallel, and then bring the whole thing together again. This is very inefficient.
2. You can have each process create part of the object, operate on it, and you're done.

Your question about nested parallelism does not make much sense. You are probably thinking of threads creating threads, but that's not how MPI works: you create a bunch of processes, and then you have those for the lifetime of the program. Yes, you can do something with sub-communicators, but I'm guessing that's over your level of understanding at the moment. Shelf that thought for later.

Comment: "You can have each process create part of the object, operate on it, and you're done." Sorry but i could not understand this sentence?,i.e. I could not understand what should i do. What is the object?

Comment: How can i do the thing that i asked in my above question by using only two RANKS (0 and 1) by using only MPI? Victor Eijkhout

Comment: you want to use MPI (each process has its own address space) but you are thinking OpenMP (threads share the same address space). If you really want to use MPI, you need to decide how data should be distributed on each ranks.